# Data is not transferred from activity to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm trying to write a data transfer from an activity to a fragment, but I'm catching "NullPointerException"
Code MainActivity:

```
val btn1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        btn1.setOnClickListener {
            BlankFragment2.getNewInstance(321)
            val fm = supportFragmentManager
            val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment, BlankFragment2())
            ft.commit()
        }
```

Code Fragment:

```
class BlankFragment2 : Fragment() {
    var str: Int = 0
    companion object {
        fun getNewInstance(args: Int): BlankFragment2 {
            val fragment = BlankFragment2()
            fragment.arguments?.putInt("one", args)
            return fragment
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        str = arguments!!.getInt("one")
        
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank2, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val txt = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textTest)
        txt.text = str.toString()
    }
}
```

I know about protection against null-values, and the problem is that I am sure that the value is passed and null cannot be there

Comment: if my answer helped can you please accept that answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of
`ft.replace(R.id.fragment, BlankFragment2()`

you should use

`ft.replace(R.id.fragment, BlankFragment2.getNewInstance(321)`.

Because your `BlankFragment2.getNewInstance(321)` statement above is kind of useless to the fragmentManager. FragmentManager is creating fragment using `BlankFragment2()` as you provided the Fragment in the `replace` call.
And that is the reason for nullpointerexception because in reality, your Fragment didn't get any int value at all as the Fragment instance used was created with the empty constructor.

And also update your companion object code like below.

```
 companion object {
        fun getNewInstance(args: Int): BlankFragment2 {
            val fragment = BlankFragment2()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putInt("one", args)
            fragment.setArguments(args)
            return fragment
        }
    }
```

because right now your code is actually not setting argument but try to access argument and setting value to it.

Comment: if it helped can you please accept this answer

Comment: I replaced but did not help, all the same "NullPointerException"

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly you are getting nullpointerexception ?

Comment: on line: str = arguments!!.getInt("one") of the function onCreateView

Comment: can you show me your new  btn1.setOnClickListener implementation after my suggestion ?

Comment: @СергейСтрельников please see the updated portion on my answer, where I recommended you to update your companion object

Comment: Please see my updated answer portion related to your companion object.

Comment: btn1.setOnClickListener {
            val fm = supportFragmentManager
            val ft = fm.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment, BlankFragment2.getNewInstance(321))
            ft.commit()
        }

Comment: Please see my updated answer portion related to your companion object.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
Correct in your answer val args = Bungle() to args1 eg, otherwise the function contains two identical variables